# IDENTITY statement issue

Tags: sql, identity-column

QUESTION:
Is it possible to roll back the maximum value of a column(using IDENTITY) after deleting some rows?

PROBLEM:
The value of column(id) doesn't reseed/roll back to the current maximum value of the column, it keeps incrementing with the last known max.

Comment: answer: no, you don't want to reset this value

Comment: what RDBS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset Identity Seed after deleting records in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why does it matter if it resets?  Let the database handle the identity for you.  If you need to change the result, then do that in your view or presentation logic with a `row_number`.  No need to reseed identity fields.

Comment: @sgeddes I see. So I should only need to use identity column for unique values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server.

The behaviour you described is the way IDENTITY columns work by design. The value for new rows is only ever incremented. This is normally used to ensure uniqueness of generated values. If you delete records, it leaves a gap in numbers. There's even a remark on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx):

> If an identity column exists for a table with frequent deletions, gaps can occur between identity values. If this is a concern, do not use the IDENTITY property.

You can reseed identity if needed or you can enter any value explicitely into an idenity column when using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` but that's not a standard usage of those columns.