# Circular IDENTITY numbers in column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity-column

Is it possible to force IDENTITY column to recalculate its seed property , when it reach maximum value for defined data type, to fill gaps in ID's.

Let say like this way, I have a column of `TINYINT` data type which can hold up values to maximum of 255. When column is filled with data to maximum ID possible, I delete one row from middle, let's say `ID = 100`.

Question is, can I force `IDENTITY` to fill that missing ID at the end?

Comment: You *can* reseed the `IDENTITY` (set a new seed), but it will **NOT** be able to magically *find* the missing values..... it'll just keep handing out new values starting at the new seed - which means, at some point, collisions with already existing values **will happen** - not a very good idea ....

Comment: You confirm my assumptions :) I was just curious if it is possible, but you gave me real answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* reseed the `IDENTITY` (set a new seed), but it will **NOT** be able to magically find the missing values.....

The reseeded `IDENTITY` column will just keep handing out new values starting at the new seed - which means, at some point, sooner or later, collisions with already existing values will happen

Therefore, all in all, reseeding an `IDENTITY` really isn't a very good idea .... Just pick a data type large enough to handle your needs.

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get *over 2 billion* possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly *922 quadrillion* (922 with 15 zeros - 9'220'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you **insert a row every second**, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you **insert one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you can do this:

```
set identity_insert on;
insert into table(id) value(100)
```

--set it off

```
set identity_insert off;
```

[Identity Insert](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Can it do by itself, without my action? I know that it is possible like your way, but I assume that is not allowed to do it automatically

Comment: No it doesn't adjust by itself look at the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server) for more info