# Select a specific number of rows in a loop when the key is not number but an alphanumeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, key, alphanumeric

I at trying to select 1000 rows from some tables in SQL Server and in some cases is easy because I do have a key which is a bigint. Thus, I store the last number of a key that I have fetched and then I add to it 100. See below:

```
--Get the last loaded record
DECLARE @StartIndex BIGINT

SET @StartIndex = 1 + (SELECT [StoredIndex]
                       FROM [DB].[dbo].[MasterData]
                       WHERE [Status] = 'LastLoad')

--Declare and set the last record that was loaded
DECLARE @EndIndex BIGINT

--Retrieve the next @Step+1 or less records and store them in a temporary table
SELECT T1.*
INTO #TempResults
FROM
    --Get the next @Step+1 or less records
    (SELECT *
     FROM ANOTHERDB.[TableName]
     WHERE [Tables_ID] BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @StartIndex + 1000) T1

--Set the index of the last record inserted
SET @EndIndex = (SELECT MAX([Tables_ID])--The next record fetched with the largest ID
                 FROM #TempResults)
```

However how to do that when the key is an alphanumeric value?

What is the equivalent for

```
WHERE [Tables_ID] BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @StartIndex + 1000
```

If the `@StartIndex` is a `nvarchar`, for example `123g7_56y7f` ?

Thank yoU!

Comment: is your `[Tables_ID]` can contains NVARCHAR data?? I don't think so

Comment: The Table_ID (thats a dummy name) is varchar(64) in the second case that i am interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you are using **SQL Server 2012 or higher** you can use `offset fetch` as below:

```
  SELECT    *
  FROM      ANOTHERDB.[TableName]
  ORDER BY  Col1 
  OFFSET XX ROWS FETCH NEXT YY ROWS ONLY;
```

*Col1 = The column which you are going to sort the data*

*XX = number of rows to be skipped*

*YY = number of rows to be fetched*

**Method 2:**

You can make use of `Row_Number` function(**SQL Server 2008 or higher**), as below:

```
  SELECT    *
  FROM      ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COL1) AS RN
          FROM      ANOTHERDB.[TableName]
        ) AS K
  WHERE     K.RN BETWEEN XX AND YY;
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables don't have a [default order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order).  So unless you can define one using the [ORDER BY clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) there is no first 1,000 or last 1,000 records.

If you are trying to return the last 1,000 records added to a table you will need to capture the date and time each record is created.  You cannot rely on an [identify column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), as these can be [reseeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server) or [updated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188059.aspx).

Combine [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) and [ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to limit the number of records returned.  An ascending order returns the first *n* results.  Descending the last *n* results.

```
-- Limits results to the last 1,000 records.
SELECT TOP 1000
    *
FROM
    YourTable
ORDER BY
    YourColumn DESC
;
```

Replace `YourTable` and `YourColumn` as needed.

Comment: Correct that's why I used Vahid's solution. Thank you all for your answers.