# reset id(primary key) after deleting record in sql

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How to reset the value after deleting particular record in sql using mvc2

ex
 records are: 1,2,3
 deleted record:3

now i am adding new record .it should have the id 3 not 4.
what can i do for that??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you provide details about the database you are using, about the structure of your table?

Comment: it just storing Employee details into sql server 2008 through MVC 2. Having the columns employee id,name,salary ...like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not a good idea if the id is associated with other tables it will make a big mess in your database, however I do not know in which context you want to use this so I leave it to your discretion.
But instead of deleting you can disable the auto incrementer of the table in question, and write a bit to add the free ids.
Obs; Continues to be a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can Reseed your table like this :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[YourTableName]', RESEED, 0);
GO
```