# How to update seed and increment parameters of a identity parameter?

Tags: sql-server

How do I alter the column for changing the  seed and increment values of a table after truncating the table.

I have created a table named table and inserted few rows into that table then I have truncated that table and want to update the seed and increment values of identity column.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset identity seed after deleting records in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: @SohelAhmed `TRUNCATE` will automatically reseed the identity column. So you don't have to manually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table', RESEED, 0);
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE` will automatically reseed the identity column. It's needed only for `DELETE`