# DbContext returns wrong id after add

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have Pin Model

```
public class Pin
{
    [Key]
    [Column("pin")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Column("desc", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have MyDbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("DbName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Pin> Pins { get; set; }
}

internal class MyDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm using MyDbContext for adding pins

```
var pin = new Pin{ Description = "Test description" };
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Pins.Add(pin);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

After `SaveChanges` is done the object `pin` has updated `Id` with value 1300 for example but according to database latest `Id` should be 1310 and 1300 is already busy. Bug appears only in one production environment, there was no possibility to reproduce on local or staging environments
Any advises about direction where to investigate is appreciated

Comment: Try and log the results after save changes so you are sure this is happening. Log.WriteLine($"pin.Id : {pin.Id}"); var testPin = context.Pins.FirstOrDefault(x => x = pin.Id); Log.WriteLine($"testPin.Description : {testPin.Description}");

Comment: Also what DB are you using

Comment: @Saruman Sorry forgot to mention I'm using MsSQL. Yes I've checked and Id is wrong - testPin is different from pin

Comment: Can you post `MyDbInitializer` code ?

Comment: which id does your pin (the one you just added) actually have when the id in the object is x? is it always higher?

Comment: I don't think this is EF problem. Most likely some identity column corruption in the problematic database. Try [reseeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server) it and see if that helps.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour I've updated post with `MyDbInitializer` code

Answer (score 0):

I would add pin to the DBSET:

```
var pin = new Pin{ Description = "Test description" };
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Pins.Add(pin);//here
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was my typo. Just fixed initial post. I'm already using `context.Pins.Add(pin)`

Comment: No  worries How many instances of dbcontext do you have spun up in production that use Pins?

Comment: It is a singleton for most cases. But there are a small amount of places where It is used with `using` as above

Comment: Ive had the same Issue before but im not sure how I created the problem, But I know for a fact that I had many DbContexts in that particular project. I only use one static Instance that gets passed around my controllers nowadays to avoid that.