# SQL Server - Reusable DML query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, reusability, dml

Good morning all,

At the moment I have this DDL:

```
    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Database name:  Zvcvolkel                                    */
    /* DBMS name:      Microsoft SQL Server 2000                    */                                                
    /*==============================================================*/

    use master
    go


    drop database Zvcvolkel
    go


    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Database: Zvcvolkel                                          */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create database Zvcvolkel
    go


    use Zvcvolkel
    go

    CREATE TABLE Rol(
        Rol_ID  int IDENTITY(1,1),
        R_Naam  varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_ROL PRIMARY KEY (Rol_ID)
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Persoon(
        Persoon_ID      int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Rol_ID          int,
        L_Voornaam      varchar(max),
        L_Achternaam    varchar(max),
        L_Geboortedat   date,
        L_Woonplaats    varchar(max),
        L_Geslacht      char(1),
        L_Rekeningnr    varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Persoon PRIMARY KEY (Persoon_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Persoon_Ref_Rol FOREIGN KEY (Rol_ID) REFERENCES Rol (Rol_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT CHK_L_geslacht CHECK (L_geslacht = 'M' OR L_geslacht = 'V')
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Medewerker(
        Medewerker_ID   int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Persoon_ID      int,
        M_Salaris       decimal,

        CONSTRAINT PK_Medewerker PRIMARY KEY (Medewerker_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Medewerker_Ref_Persoon FOREIGN KEY (Persoon_ID) REFERENCES Persoon (Persoon_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT CHK_M_Salaris CHECK (M_Salaris >= 0)
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Lid(
        Lid_ID          int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Persoon_ID      int,
        L_GebNaam       varchar(max),
        L_Wachtwoord    varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Lid PRIMARY KEY (Lid_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Lid_Ref_Persoon FOREIGN KEY (Persoon_ID) REFERENCES Persoon (Persoon_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Stat(
        Status_ID   int IDENTITY(1,1),
        S_Naam      varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Stat PRIMARY KEY (Status_ID)
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Hangaar(
        Hangaar_ID  int IDENTITY(1,1),
        H_Naam      varchar(max),
        H_Locatie   varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Hangaar PRIMARY KEY (Hangaar_ID)
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Vliegtuig(
        Vliegtuig_ID    int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Hangaar_ID      int,
        Status_ID       int,
        V_Naam          varchar(max),
        V_Type          varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Vliegtuig PRIMARY KEY (Vliegtuig_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vliegtuig_Ref_Hangaar FOREIGN KEY (Hangaar_ID) REFERENCES Hangaar (Hangaar_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vliegtuig_Ref_Status FOREIGN KEY (Status_ID) REFERENCES Stat (Status_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    )
    go

    CREATE TABLE Vlucht(
        Vlucht_ID       int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Lid_ID          int,
        Vliegtuig_ID    int,
        Vl_Vertrektijd  date,
        VL_Eindtijd     date,
        VL_Type         char(1),
        Vl_Notitie      varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Vlucht PRIMARY KEY (Vlucht_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vlucht_Ref_Lid FOREIGN KEY (Lid_ID) REFERENCES Lid (Lid_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vlucht_Ref_Vliegtuig FOREIGN KEY (Vliegtuig_ID) REFERENCES Vliegtuig (Vliegtuig_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT CHK_VL_type CHECK (VL_type = 'R' OR VL_type = 'L')

    )
    go
```

Next up is the creation of a DML file which is reusable:

```
    use Zvcvolkel
    go

    DELETE FROM Vlucht
    DELETE FROM Medewerker
    DELETE FROM Lid
    DELETE FROM Persoon
    DELETE FROM Rol
    DELETE FROM Vliegtuig
    DELETE FROM Stat
    DELETE FROM Hangaar

    go

    INSERT INTO Rol 
    VALUES  ('Management'),
            ('Instructeur'),
            ('Technicus'),
            ('Lid'),
            ('Bartender')

    INSERT INTO Stat 
    VALUES  ('Beschikbaar'),
            ('Niet beschikbaar'),
            ('Onderhoud')

    INSERT INTO Hangaar 
    VALUES  ('Hangaar 1', 'Volkel'),
            ('Hangaar 2', 'Volkel')

    INSERT INTO Vliegtuig 
    VALUES  (1, 1, 'PH-143', 'ASK-21'),
            (1, 3, 'PH-1643', 'LS-4'),
            (2, 2, 'PH-831', 'Ka-8')

    INSERT INTO Persoon
    VALUES  (1, 'Chef', 'de Directeur', '01-01-1986', 'Eindhoven', 'M', 'IBAN7277'),
            (2, 'Piet', 'de Instructeur', '02-02-1965', 'Geldrop', 'M', 'IBAN5656'), 
            (3, 'Monica', 'de Technicus', '03-03-1958', 'Helmond', 'V', 'IBAN8579'),
            (4, 'Linda', 'het Lid', '04-04-1976', 'Deurne', 'V', 'IBAN4665'),
            (5, 'Jan', 'de Bartender', '05-05-1966', 'Venray', 'M', 'IBAN5765')

    INSERT INTO Medewerker
    VALUES  (5, 1250.00)

    INSERT INTO Lid
    VALUES  (1, 'Chefgeb', 'Chefww'),
            (2, 'Pietgeb', 'Pietww'),
            (3, 'Monicageb', 'Monicaww'),
            (4, 'Lindageb', 'Lindaww')

    INSERT INTO Vlucht
    VALUES  (2, 1, '10-04-2018 10:34:00', '10-04-2018 17:34:00', 'R', 'Geen notitie')
```

It works perfectly on the first run, but when I run it again it adds the rows again and it screws over the ID's because of auto increment. When I run the query again the Rol_ID become 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 instead of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5! Everytime I run the ID's increase, where it should start at 1 again because of the Delete statement on the first lines.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: Replace the delete with truncate. truncate table a, truncate table b... etc

Comment: Msg 4712, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot truncate table 'Lid' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: Then do a `DBCC CHECKIDENT(..., RESEED)` after the deletes. However, finding a way to start entirely from scratch (all tables included) is cleaner still.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server to reset the identity seed back to a known starting point.

Comment: If you know beforehand what you want the values to be, why use an identity? Either take the identity attribute off the column or use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` to enable explicit insert of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

for all tables which use `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 1):

you need reset identity counter

The DBCC CHECKIDENT management command is used to reset identity counter. The command syntax is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ]}}])
```

for example

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Vliegtuig', RESEED, 0);
```

GO

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to reset identity counter to 0 for all tables using below statement.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ]}}])
```