# How to Specifiy Primary Key Starting Number in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, identity-column

There is a table named `User` in database. Columns as follows:

```
ID
FirstName
LastName
```

`ID` is primary key and auto incremented in this case. I have only 7 records; last ID of data is 7.

How can I increment ID starting from any number (eg. 10000).

Comment: please specify database engine

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: your answer is here  https://forums.asp.net/t/1950215.aspx?Primary+Key+start+value+as+1000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : alter the Identity seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507374/sql-server-alter-the-identity-seed)

Comment: Why did you answer the question then?

Comment: that's why i deleted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this. `CHECKIDENT` is use to reseed the value of your identity column. 
For more info you may find this link.[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Yourtable', RESEED, yournumber);    ---- here yournumber is the number to reseed.
```