# A new Item ID appears after the database is emptied

Tags: c#, sql

I was working on a trivia app that gets the questions from a .txt file and then stores them in a database.

I have created a table named "Itemi" to store the question, which type of question is,four possible answers and the right answer.

Everytime I open the app, I delet all the data from the table and then insert it again. I did that to make the app portable. The .txt file is located in the "Debug" folder.

The problme is, although the table is deleted everytime I open the app and isert again the same data, the ID is not changing. Here is the commnad I used to delete the data.

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Itemi", sqc);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cmd.Dispose();
```

For example, this is how the id column looks like when I open the app:
[image]
As you can see, the Id is between 33-59.

If I run the app again: 
[image]
The Ids changed

Is there a way I can avoid thhis ? I want the Ids to be between 1 and 30. I forgot to mention that the Id column has the primary key.

Comment: It's an identity column.  You need to set the next ID to be generated.  Google "sql server reseed identity column".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server

Comment: Also, your title is misleading.  You didn't delete the database, or even a table.  You emptied the table.

Comment: Why you need to delete the data ?

Comment: Thank you, for the link @Amy. And no intetion for clickbait.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the Identity after deleting the data (the query you run).

From [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21824729/5274951) this is the command you need

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ]}}])
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Comment: Thanks, had a hard time finding the answers !